# Python - модуль datetime в телеграмм боте

Tags: telegram, бот, datetime

требуется сделать так что-бы бот понимал какой сегодня день недели с помощью модуля datetime.weekday(), и при нажатии на кнопку "Расписание на сегодня (Временно недоступно)", выдавал результат с сегодняшний день недели,
Т.е Если сегодня четверг, нужно воспроизвести  elif (message.text == "Четверг"):
Если пятница, соответственно  elif (message.text == "Пятница"):

Код:

````
import datetime
import telebot
from telebot import types # для указание типов
token='**************************************'
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)


today = datetime.date.today()
week = datetime.datetime.isoweekday(today)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на сегодня (Временно недоступно)")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на завтра")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Чаты GPT')
    markup.add(btn1, btn3, btn4)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, {0.first_name}! Я бот, в котором ты сможешь узнать расписание.\nСегодня: {1}".format(message.from_user, today), reply_markup=markup)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if(message.text == "Расписание на другой день"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        back = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню")
        pn = types.KeyboardButton("Понедельник")
        vt = types.KeyboardButton("Вторник")
        sr = types.KeyboardButton("Среда")
        ch = types.KeyboardButton("Четверг")
        pt = types.KeyboardButton("Пятница")
        sb = types.KeyboardButton("Суббота")

        markup.add(pn, vt, sr, ch, pt, sb, back,)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Расписание на другой день", reply_markup=markup)

    elif (message.text == "Чаты GPT"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на сегодня (Временно недоступно)")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на завтра")
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Чаты GPT')
        markup.add(btn1, btn3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=gpt, reply_markup=markup)

    elif (message.text == "Понедельник"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        markup.add(button1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=pon, reply_markup=markup)

    elif (message.text == "Вторник"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        markup.add(button1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=vto, reply_markup=markup)
    
    elif (message.text == "Среда"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        markup.add(button1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=sre, reply_markup=markup)

    elif (message.text == "Четверг"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        markup.add(button1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=che, reply_markup=markup)

    elif (message.text == "Пятница"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        markup.add(button1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=pat, reply_markup=markup)

    elif (message.text == "Суббота"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        markup.add(button1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=sub, reply_markup=markup)

    elif (message.text == "Расписание на сегодня (Временно недоступно)"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на сегодня (Временно недоступно)")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на завтра")
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Чаты GPT')
        markup.add(btn1, btn3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=ponedel, reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Расписание на сегодня (Временно недоступно)', reply_markup=markup)

    elif (message.text == "Вернуться в главное меню"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на сегодня (Временно недоступно)")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на завтра")
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Расписание на другой день")
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Чаты GPT')
        markup.add(btn1, btn3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Вы вернулись в главное меню\nСегодня: {1}".format(message.from_user, today), reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`day_id = datetime.datetime.isoweekday(today)` возвращает номер дня недели. Соответственно, можно создать словарь вида `номерДня: названиеДня`:

```
week_days = {
        1: 'Понедельник',
        2: 'Вторник',
        3: 'Среда',
        4: 'Четверг',
        5: 'Пятница',
        6: 'Суббота',
        7: 'Воскресенье',
    }
```

Обернуть получение название текущего дня в функцию, назовем её, например, `get_day_name()`:

```
def get_day_name():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    day_id = datetime.datetime.isoweekday(today)
    week_days = {
        1: 'Понедельник',
        2: 'Вторник',
        3: 'Среда',
        4: 'Четверг',
        5: 'Пятница',
        6: 'Суббота',
        7: 'Воскресенье',
    }
    return week_days[day_id]
```

И в хендлере проверять `message.text` и название, полученное из функции `get_day_name()`:

```
def get_day_name():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    day_id = datetime.datetime.isoweekday(today)
    week_days = {
        1: 'Понедельник',
        2: 'Вторник',
        3: 'Среда',
        4: 'Четверг',
        5: 'Пятница',
        6: 'Суббота',
        7: 'Воскресенье',
    }
    return week_days[day_id]

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    current_day = get_day_name()
    elif (message.text == "Понедельник" == current_day ):
        ...
    elif (message.text == "Вторник" == current_day ):
        ...
    ...
```